# Parallel processing middleware

Tags: parallel-processing, rpc, xml-rpc, corba

For relatively coarse-grained parallel processing (data transfers can be done in 100 Mbit Ethernet network), which middleware that is available for Windows and Linux do you consider best? CORBA? MPI1? MPI2? XML-RPC/SOA/WSDL? Custom network protocols? Java RPC? Python RPC? Others?

Comment: Can you provide some more info on your problem domain?  What are you trying to compute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PVM](http://www.epm.ornl.gov/pvm/) was very useful to me for a small (10 machine, 40 processor) cluster with a GigE switch. This was a couple years ago, but should still be viable, though PVM does not seem to be evolving any further. I mention it to add it to you list of candidates. I suspect MPI would be a more popular choice, but I liked PVM.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about middleware, but then specifying a series of messaging protocols.  If you're looking for messaging protocols, the Thrift framework from Facebook is definitely something that works under very high load and cluster size:

[Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/)

If you're looking for some other component of middleware, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/)? Or may be [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)?